# Cannot read property 'helpers' of undefined

Tags: javascript, meteor

Meteor came out of beta, and I am very excited to use it. I installed it on my windows machine (from http://win.meteor.com/) and created an app. Here's the code:

**html:**

```
<!-- simple-todos.html -->
<head>
  <title>Todo List</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <h1>Todo List</h1>
    </header>

    <ul>
      {{#each tasks}}
        {{> task}}
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

<template name="task">
  <li>{{text}}</li>
</template>
```

**javascript:**

```
// simple-todos.js
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  // This code only runs on the client
  Template.body.helpers({
    tasks: [
      { text: "This is task 1" },
      { text: "This is task 2" },
      { text: "This is task 3" }
    ]
  });
}
```

It is the exact same code as in the [official meteor tutorial](https://www.meteor.com/try/2). If I run the example, the title is rendered just fine. The list on the other hand doesn't appear at all. Somehow, the helpers do not work. I get the following javascript error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'helpers' of undefined

In the meteor console, no error or warning was printed. I am very excited about meteor and I would love to use it in the future for production apps, so please help me with this (probably very simple) problem. I hope it is not only a problem in windows (meteor hasn't yet been officially released for windows).

Comment: First thing I'd do is add `console.dir(Template);` before the attempted call to `.helpers()`. The issue is that `.body` is `undefined`, so it'd be useful to figure out what `Template` actually looks like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Template needs to be defined by `<template name="xxx">`.

There is no helper on the `<body>` element.

You could use a global helper for this, though:

```
Template.registerHelper("tasks", function() {
    return [....]
});
```

An alternative is to use `<template name="body">`:

```
<body>
    {{>body}}
</body>

<template name="body">
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <h1>Todo List</h1>
    </header>

    <ul>
      {{#each tasks}}
        {{> task}}
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: The docs disagree, using `Template.body.helpers` should work fine. https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_body

Comment: @PeppeL-G yes you're right. I thought they deprecated this with the UI->Template transition